# undefined method `user_verification_path' (has_one relationship)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, controller

I have a has_one relation with `verification` and `user`. I want to make a form that references both!! How can I do this? I run into this error!!! Thanks!

**errorlog:**

```html
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user_verification_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fcb8bb4e8e0>:0x007fcb89e71998>):
    1: <%= form_for([@user, @user.verification]) do |f| %>
    2:  <%= f.email_field :paypal_email, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Paypal Email", id: 'Pemail' %>
    3: <%= f.text_field :paypal_firstname, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Paypal FirstName", id: 'PfirstName' %>
    4: <%= f.text_field :paypal_lastname, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Paypal LastName", id: 'PlastName' %>
  app/views/users/paypal_verification.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users_paypal_verification_html_erb__139977708174630313_70256084327900'
```

**Here is my form paypal html**

```html
<%= form_for([@user, @user.verification]) do |f| %>
 <%= f.email_field :paypal_email, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Paypal Email", id: 'Pemail' %>
<%= f.text_field :paypal_firstname, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Paypal FirstName", id: 'PfirstName' %>
<%= f.text_field :paypal_lastname, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Paypal LastName", id: 'PlastName' %>


<%= f.submit "verify", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**Here is my controller!!!**

```rails
def paypal_verification
    # @verification = @user.verification.new
    @user = current_user
@verification = Verification.create(params[:verification])
@user.verification = @verification
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```rails
 devise_for :users ,
       :path => '' ,
       :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :edit => 'profile'},
       :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks',
                :registrations => 'registrations', :verifications => 'verifications'
              }


 resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do

 end
 resources :revisers
 resources :photos
 resources :pages

 #make sure to change this to user!!! instead of reservations!!!
resources :reviser do
  resources :reservations, only: [:create]
end


resources :user do
  resources :verifications, only: [:create]
end


get '/preload' => 'reservations#preload'
get '/preview' => 'reservations#preview'

get '/your_essays' => 'reservations#your_essays'
get '/your_reservations' => 'reservations#your_reservations'

post '/notify' => 'reservations#notify'
post '/your_essays' => 'reservations#your_essays'

get '/users/:id/paypal_verification' => 'users#paypal_verification'
```

Comment: Can you post your route file? Do you have alias post route with as: :user_verification?

Comment: I made an edit!! Thanks Mirza!!

Comment: i changed resources :user do
  resource :verification, only: [:create]
end        Now I get this error  No route matches [PATCH] "/user/3/verification.27"

Comment: Look at my answer below...if you are doing a PATCH then your form needs to say...form_for(@user.verification, url: user_verifications_path(@user, @user.verification)....You need to pass in url after form and then look at bin/rails route alias that you have set for this form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing a nested route to do the verification rails will expect this route:

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
 user_verifications POST   /user/:user_id/verifications(.:format) verifications#create
```

You can check with bin/rails routes

So in your form you need to use user_verifications_path but since you have instance variables here is what you need to do

```
<%= form_for([@user, @user.verification]) do |f| %>
```

That line should say this

```
<%= form_for(Verification.new, url: user_verifications_path(@user)) do |f| %>
```

Uer verification will go to /users/ID/verifications with a Verifications.new as new model that you pass in to your controller. This should be inside verifications#create. You have not included this controller in your question. So if this does not work please update your question with this method as well.

EDIT

if you want to update already created verification then for PATH/ or put the only thing that is change is instance of record and path, so it goes to /users/ID/verifications/VERIFICATIONID

Your form needs to say something like this

```
form_for(@user.verification, url: user_verifications_path(@user, @user.verification)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: with ngrok it changes from user 4 to user 3... weird but with local host its fine!! and goes through now i just have an error in the next page that doesnt relate to this question but you could probably answer it so ill make another question!! thank you!!

Comment: I have noticed that my database creates a new verification everytime Ioad the page before submission. Shouldnt the same one stay?

Comment: I think is because of this line @verification = Verification.create(params[:verification]). This method is get def paypal_verification so I assume that you want there to prepare the form before user verifies the account. In get you should only do @ verification = Verification.new and then inside form when it is submitted verification is created. Not sure if you also need to verify if user has been already verified. In that case you can do before_action and redirect with flash message saying You already are verified...etc

Comment: yessir!! i figured it out!! hahah iv been staying up late working, so I miss these things sometimes!! thanks a lot!!!